# Couldn't find package "libapache2-mod-proxy-html" Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, proxy, mod-proxy

I want to install `libapache2-mod-proxy-html` package but  it gives me error. Just to check what packages are available, I pressed tab after the command below.

```
devadmin@Dev-LinuxVM:/$ aptitude install -y libapache2-mod-proxy-
```

> libapache2-mod-proxy-msrpc      libapache2-mod-proxy-uwsgi-dbg
> libapache2-mod-proxy-uwsgi

```
devadmin@Dev-LinuxVM:/$ aptitude install -y libapache2-mod-proxy-html
```

> Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "libapache2-mod-proxy-html"
> Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "libapache2-mod-proxy-html"
> No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
> 0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (xenial)

Comment: where did you find name `libapache2-mod-proxy-html` ? Maybe real name is different or this module is not in standard repozytory and you have to download .deb file or source code.

Comment: maybe first try to search `libapache2` in `aptitude`/`apt`/`synaptic`. It should show all packages with `libapache2` in name.

Comment: @furas https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scaling-couchdb/9781449304942/ch04.html

Comment: please search for the word "Proxy Server Configuration" in the above link

Answer (score 23):

`libapache2-mod-proxy-html` was a transitional package for `apache2-bin`.

Since the translation is completed it should be already included in the `apache2-bin` Xenial package.
In fact you can find the `mod_proxy_html.so` file in the [apache2-bin file list (Xenial)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/apache2-bin/filelist).

My guess is that the command

```
a2enmod proxy_html
```

should solve the issue.

As a final note: you should probably post the question on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).